# Alternative to using a switch for setting state ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, switch-statement, state

I've made a function in React for hiding filters.
I have multiple filter components inside a container component, each filter component has a corresponding state to add a hide/show css class.

I was wondering if someone knows a better way/ of programming this function, because it feels kind of tedious to program it this manner..

```
hideFilters(clickedFilter){
  switch(clickedFilter.toLowerCase()){
    case "assortiment":
      this.setState({
          "assortiment": "show",
          "taal":"hide",
          "bestelbaar":"hide",
          "verschijningsjaar":"hide",
          "verschijningsvorm":"hide",
          "nur":"hide"
      });
      break;
    case "bestelbaar":
      this.setState({
          "bestelbaar":"show",
          "assortiment": "hide",
          "taal":"hide",
          "verschijningsjaar":"hide",
          "verschijningsvorm":"hide",
          "nur":"hide"
      });
      break;
    case "taal":
      this.setState({
          "taal":"show",
          "assortiment": "hide",
          "bestelbaar":"hide",
          "verschijningsjaar":"hide",
          "verschijningsvorm":"hide",
          "nur":"hide"
      });
      break;
    case "verschijningsvorm":
      this.setState({
          "verschijningsvorm":"show",
          "assortiment": "hide",
          "bestelbaar":"hide",
          "verschijningsjaar":"hide",
          "taal":"hide",
          "nur":"hide"
      });
      break;
    case "verschijningsjaar":
      this.setState({
          "verschijningsjaar":"show",
          "assortiment": "hide",
          "bestelbaar":"hide",
          "verschijningsvorm":"hide",
          "taal":"hide",
          "nur":"hide"
      });
      break;
    default:  console.log('hi')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
this.defaultStates = {
  "assortiment": "hide",
  "taal":"hide",
  "bestelbaar":"hide",
  "verschijningsjaar":"hide",
  "verschijningsvorm":"hide"
}

hideFilters(clickedFilter){
  this.setState({
    ...this.defaultStates,
    [clickedFilter.toLowerCase()]: "show"
  })
}
```